# Java program with multiple windows(JPanel), how to connect them to JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have a library application that permits users to log in, and many other things.

I don't really know how to make multiple windows (views), such as a login, and if it is succesfull, closing the current window and opening the other user interface.

I hope that I have been clear.

Comment: as far i have never worked with multiple windows i know how to work with one but i dont know waht should i do is there some way to repaint the jframe, or idk.

Comment: i have three jpanels each one in different file and from there im stuck

Comment: Use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Or remove the first panel, add the second one, and revalidate.

Comment: Generally, you use JPanels for views that the user will work with, and JDialogs for things like log on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer: Suppose your three `JPanel` extensions are called `MyLoginPanel`, `MyWelcomePanel`, and `MyFormPanel`. I'm assuming the form you mention would be the *main* class, among these, instead of the actual components that make a form.

Each of these panels should take care of its own components.

Looking at the code below, you have only to find-and-replace my names with the ones you're using.

Suggestion: Make your *main* class implement some interface, to listen to changes on the three distinct panels. E.g.: The user clicked on some button that should make the application progress to the next panel. That button has to inform someone. That someone would be the implementer of the interface.

---

```
enum AppState {
    LOGIN, WELCOME, FORM
}
```

---

```
interface ProgressListener {
    void progressFrom(AppState currentState);
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyForm implements Runnable, ProgressListener {
    // instance variables
    private JFrame frame;
    private MyLoginPanel loginPanel;
    private MyWelcomePanel welcomePanel;
    private MyFormPanel formPanel;

    /** Empty constructor of objects of class SomeClassUI. */
    public SomeClassUI() {
        // ...
    }

    /** Interface initialization. */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // These should handle their own component initialization.
        // They should, at least, receive a reference to the listener.

        loginPanel = new MyLoginPanel(this);
        welcomePanel = new MyWelcomePanel(this);
        formPanel = new MyFormPanel(this);

        frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(loginPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** */
    @Override
    public void progressFrom(AppState whoTriggeredIt) {
        switch (whoTriggeredIt) {
            case LOGIN:
            frame.setContentPane(welcomePanel);
            frame.pack();
            return;

            case WELCOME:
            frame.setContentPane(formPanel);
            frame.pack();
            return;

            default: return;
        }
    }


    /** */
    public void go() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
    }


    /** */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClassUI().go();
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyLoginPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public MyLoginPanel(ProgressListener listener) {
        // Components, etc.
        this.listener = listener;
    }

        ...

    /** */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Validate login, or whatever.
        // All went well, notify listener to progress.
        this.listener.progressFrom(AppState.LOGIN);
    }
}
```

Instead of adding / removing elements directly from the `JFrame`, you may want to do these things on some *content panel* of your own, which you store as an instance variable (see `JFrame.setContentPane()`).

If you want all the panels to be easily accessible *at the same time*, instead of this *procedural* step-by-step change, you may want to look into the [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), as previously suggested in the comments.

The suggestions I give are just general guidelines, as I'm not aware of the details of your needs.

Comment: I would like to ask another thing, it works the way you told me, and now i know how to add jpanels to the frame dispose them and so on. But i have 3 different classes that extend the jpannel so i have 3 files for them then i have another file that stands for the form, but i have no idea how to bind them all together, because i have to make the action listener inside the login jpanel class and from there i cant call function from the form class. im all messed up

Comment: @user1870530 I've updated my answer. I hope it clears some of your confusion.